# IBM Watson Assistant search skill inside a dialog node always returns 3 results

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

Basically I have a data collection on IBM Discovery, I can query stuff on the query builder just right, and the queries such as name::@productName work well.
The deal is that the search skill always returns 3 results no matter what, can I change the number of results I get?

In the query builder, in the More Options section I can decide how many results to retrieve, however in the Dialog Node in the Search Skill I can't change it for some reason, even if I add something along the lines like Group::@clothing, Size::"S", count:5, if I do that I'll get still 3 results, and the results I get would be incorrect, but if I remove the count it'll retrieve 3 CORRECT results.

How do I make the Search Skill retrieve more than 3 results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, 3 items are returned and displayed when using "Try it out", preview link or Web chat. Because the 10 top matching items are returned from Discovery, you can configure up to 10 results when using a custom integration.